# how to use tapply for repeated data in R

Tags: r, tapply

this is my dataframe:

```
x day month
5 1 1
4 1 1 
1 2 1
3 2 1
5 1 2
2 1 2
5 2 2
3 2 2
```

I need to take the sum of x values for each day in each month.
I already have tried:

```
tapply(DF$x, DF$day, max)
```

but it is not giving the right answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
DT<-data.table(df)
DT[, list(Sum=sum(x)), by = c("day","month")]

    day month Sum
1:   1     1  9
2:   2     1  4
3:   1     2  7
4:   2     2  8
```

**OR** use the `sqldf` package:

```
sqldf("select  day, month, sum(x) as sum from DT group by day, month")
```

**OR** using the base `aggregate` function:

```
aggregate(DT$x, FUN=sum, by = list(DT$day, DT$month))
```

**a more cleaner way suggested by Frank:**

```
aggregate(x~day+month, DT, sum)
```

**OR** using the `dplyr` package: (As suggested by Frank)

```
DT %>% 
    group_by(day,month) %>% 
    summarise(Sum = sum(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

As the question title is about `tapply` and the `right answer` is not in the OP's post, if we need a cross-tabular version, one option with `tapply` would be to place the grouping variables in a `list` and specify the `FUN` as `sum`

```
with(DF, tapply(x, list(day, month), FUN=sum))
#  1 2
#1 9 7
#2 4 8
```

---

Or this can be done with `xtabs`.  The default option is `sum`

```
xtabs(x~day+month, DF)
#    month
#day 1 2
#   1 9 7
#   2 4 8
```

---

Or with `by`

```
by(DF[1], DF[-1], FUN= sum)
```